# How to make 2 blocks "div" go in a row

Tags: html, css

I need my two blocks to go in a row one after another, but when the screen resolution decreases, they are placed under each other, that is, in the column
[image]

```html
 <div>            
    <div>
        <h1>Block1</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Block2</h1>
    </div>                        
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use flex (by default `flex-direction` is `row` so we don't need any other styling in css) -:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
      <h1>Block1</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Block2</h1>
    </div>
</div>


.container{
    display: flex;
}
```

Also this is one way of doing things, `flex` is not supported everywhere so you can go for `inline-block` also -:

```
<div>
    <div class="inline">
      <h1>Block1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="inline">
        <h1>Block2</h1>
    </div>
</div>

.inline{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Be sure to check out the other parameters you can set with flex. It's really... flexible (forgive me).

Comment: yeah but in this specific case `justify-content` will be `start`, which is default value and `align-items` will be `center` which is also default value.

Comment: @JochemKuijpers I think what he means is flex is not supported on all browsers....

Comment: @AbhisarTripathi [Check This](https://medium.com/@ohansemmanuel/flexbox-is-awesome-but-its-not-welcome-here-a90601c292b6). It's severely misused in several cases. It's also best to use display:inline-block in the example above. [CanIUse can be used to show flexbox's compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: @jbutler483 I have added that approach in my answer also I have written the same point there also about browser compatibility.

Comment: @AbhisarTripathi Flex is well-supported for over 7 years now.

Answer (score 2):

As the `div` element is known as a block element, you need to use `display:inline-block`. This means 'if there is space next to the element, place the next inline block element next to it' (in essence).

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background:tomato;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div{
  display:block;
  background:green;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div>1
  </div>
  <div>2
  </div>
</div>
```

For your width to then turn back into a block element, you will need to use the `media` query - something like above.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS grid:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <h1>Block1</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Block2</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.wrapper{
   diplay: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display:flex` and use flexbox to place next to each other when the width is high. When the width reduces the div cols will go down.

```css
.row {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cols {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cols">
  </div>
  <div class="cols">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
    div{
       float: left; 
       width: 98%;
       margin-left: 1%; 
       overflow: hidden;
       border: 1px solid #000;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       padding: 5px;
    }
}
```

Or with class

```
.wrapper div{
    ...
}
```

More about @media
https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries